# What is the correct date format (NSDateFormatter)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse this date : 2016-04-16T10:00:00-0400 but I don't know what is '-0400' in this case ?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss<?>"];
                                                 ^^^
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2016-04-16T10:00:00-0400"];
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Read the NSDateFormatter documentation carefully. Find the link to the Unicode standard in the documentation which lists all the date formats.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I found the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
//[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2016-04-16T10:00:00-0400"];
NSLog(@"date ==%@",date);
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *finalStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"finalStr ==%@",finalStr);
```

output like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gnasher729 for the tip, here is the Date Field Symbol Table  : http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

The answer is for the date 2016-04-16T10:00:00-0400 is :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```